# Surface Plotting on Python 2.7 with pyplot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, mplot3d, data-files

I am new to Python. I have been trying to plot a data file that contains 3 columns and 1024 data points. While running the code the following error arises:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot-data.py", line 27, in <module>
    linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
  File "/home/ritajit/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1624, in plot_surface
    X, Y, Z = np.broadcast_arrays(X, Y, Z)
  File "/home/ritajit/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 249, in broadcast_arrays
    shape = _broadcast_shape(*args)
  File "/home/ritajit/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy            /lib/stride_tricks.py", line 184, in _broadcast_shape
b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

My code looks like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import matplotlib.cm as cm    
from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 9, 9


## 3D surface_plot
fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') #gca = get current axis

data = np.loadtxt('2D-data.txt')
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
z = data[:,2]

xi = np.unique(x)
yi = np.unique(y)

xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')

# surface_plot with color grading and color bar
p = axes.plot_surface(xv,yv,Z, rstride=4, cstride=4, cmap=cm.RdBu, 
    linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
fig.colorbar(p, shrink=0.5)

axes.set_xlabel('$x$',fontsize=15)
axes.set_ylabel('$y$',fontsize=15)
axes.set_zlabel('$z$',fontsize=15)
plt.tight_layout()
fig.savefig("surface.pdf")
plt.show()
```

I am unable to work this through.
**What wrong am I doing?

Is there any other way to plot 3d datafile?**

A few lines from my data file:

```
1 2 1.30884
2 2 1.30925
3 2 1.30974
4 2 1.30841
5 2 1.30864
6 2 1.30795
```

The 1st,2nd,3rd columns are x,y,z respectively

Comment: you gridded your data into `Z`, but then tried to plot the 1-d array `z`. Use `Z` instead

Comment: @PaulH  I changed from 'z' to 'Z' but still new errors occur

Answer (score 1):

Three main issues here:

- You need to meshgrid the unique values, not the original ones

  ```
  xi = np.unique(x)
  yi = np.unique(y)
  xv, yv = np.meshgrid(xi,yi)
  ```
- You need to interpolate on the gridded values

  ```
  griddata(x, y, z, xv, yv)
  ```
- You need to plot `Z`, not `z`

  ```
  p = axes.plot_surface(xv,yv,Z)
  ```

In total it looks like you could achieve pretty much the same by reshaping the data columns (but the small data excerpt is not enough to judge on this).

Last, `matplotlib.mlab.griddata` will be deprecated in the next version. As an alternative consider `scipy.interpolate.griddata`. Also have a look at the [Contour plot of irregularly spaced data](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/irregulardatagrid.html) example.

Comment: thanks for the response. I've straighten up all errors in the code now it shows this, **ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional**    can't figure it out.

Comment: That's the usual problem of answering questions which do not provide a [mcve]. You are assuming that people can solve your problem by just looking at the code. I updated the answer for now.